# Combining Rows into Comma Separated Rows by Increments

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the dataframe below.

```r
A
25
12
32
52
56
98
96
53
25
22
```

I would like to transform N rows in increments of 5 into a new column where the values are comma seperated, like below.

```r
A
25,12,32,52,56
98,96,53,25,22
```

I have been playing around with dplyr/mutate but have not had much success. Is this possible to do in R?

temp_df <- temp_df %>%
dplyr::summarise(duration = paste(duration, collapse = ","))

Answer (score 1):

One potential option is to convert the dataframe into a matrix then use `unite()` from the [tidyr package](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html), e.g.

```r
library(tidyr)

A <- c(25,
       12,
       32,
       52,
       56,
       98,
       96,
       53,
       25,
       22)
df <- data.frame(A = A)

matrix(as.matrix(df), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  unite(everything(), col = "A", sep = ",")
#>                A
#> 1 25,12,32,52,56
#> 2 98,96,53,25,22
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

NB this will only work if your column is a multiple of 5 (i.e. 20 rows will work, 21 rows won't)

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 5) %>%
  summarise(A = paste(A, collapse = ","))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
    grp A             
  <dbl> <chr>         
1     0 25,12,32,52,56
2     1 98,96,53,25,22
```

Comment: Just tried, and this also works. Thank you.